# Method Set.prototype.add called on incompatible receiver undefined

Tags: javascript

I simply can't understand why it gives this error.

Here is what I tested on my chrome's console:

```
>    var mySet;
<-   undefined

>    mySet = new Set;
<-   Set {}

>    mySet.add('foo', 'bar', 'baz')       // Worked as expected
<-   Set {"foo"}                          // just the first argument was added

>    ['bar', 'baz'].forEach(mySet.add)
X->  VM1529:1 Uncaught TypeError: 
         Method Set.prototype.add called on incompatible receiver undefined(…)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `forEach(mySet.add.bind(mySet))` - `.add()` must use `this` internally...

Comment: `['bar', 'baz'].forEach(mySet.add, mySet)`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In this case `add` method loses its internal `this` context when you pass it as a callback, so you need to use `bind`:

```
['bar', 'baz'].forEach(mySet.add.bind(mySet));
```

or

```
['bar', 'baz'].forEach((item) => mySet.add(item));
```

Comment: @user6188402: yeah. arrow function are handy when you don't need to support mobile or IE

Comment: @dandavis: Given that we use `Set`, we surely also can use arrow functions :-)

Comment: @Bergi: well i've been using Map and Set for years but arrows are fairly recent...

Comment: The second argument to `forEach` and `map` is `thisArg`: an argument to bind this to, so you can shorten this to: `.map(mySet.add, mySet)` (`map` isn't really any slower than `.forEach`).