# Method Set.prototype.has called on incompatible receiver undefined

Tags: javascript

After years of using JavaScript I met an error that I had never seen.

I wanted to calculate the intersection between two *Set*s, so I wrote:

```js
let a = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
let b = new Set([2, 3, 4]);

let intersection = [...a].filter(x => b.has(x));

console.log(intersection);
```

And it works, but I noticed that I can shorten the above code. Since the filter method just wants a function and invokes it no matter how it is defined, and I  wrote:

```js
let a = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
let b = new Set([2, 3, 4]);

let intersection = [...a].filter(b.has);

console.log(intersection);
```

And in this case, unexpectedly, I receive the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Method Set.prototype.has called on incompatible receiver undefined

I also noticed that this doesn't happen if I bind `Set.prototype.add` to the variable:

```js
let a = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
let b = new Set([2, 3, 4]);

let intersection = [...a].filter(Set.prototype.bind(b));

console.log(intersection);
```

My question is: why does it happen? Why `b.has` is not a valid callback?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method Set.prototype.add called on incompatible receiver undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199019/method-set-prototype-add-called-on-incompatible-receiver-undefined)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`has` method loses internal `this` context when you pass it as a callback.

That is the reason it works when you use `bind` to provide it right context.

For more info it has been documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Called_on_incompatible_type)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function and pass `thisArg` as the second parameter. So the `has` will take this second parameter as it's `this`, and proceeds to evaluate or compare.

Here's an example:

```js
function compare(a, b) {
    return [...a].filter(Set.prototype.has, b);
}

let a = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
let b = new Set([2, 3, 4]);

console.log(compare(a, b));
```

Another idea:

```js
function compare(a, b) {
    return new Set([...a].filter(Set.prototype.has, b));
}

let a = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
let b = new Set([2, 3, 4]);

console.log([...compare(a, b).values()]);
```

Comment: So a shorter version could be `filter(b.has, b)`. It works, thank you